# copy data from a table in access to an existing excel file

Tags: vba, ms-access

I would like to copy records from a table or a query into an existing excel file on my folder

my code exports the data into a new excel file. it won't work with the current file  that i have define here path = CurrentProject.path & "\"& "BTO Export.xlsx"

```
Private Sub cmdGetIDs_Click()

DoCmd.SetWarnings False

Dim db As Database
Dim rs As Recordset
Set db = CurrentDb

Dim path As String

path = CurrentProject.path & "\"& "BTO Export.xlsx"

Dim mySql As String

 On Error GoTo HandleError

mySql = "SELECT DISTINCT TABLEDD.[Code] as [ID] From TABLEDD"

 On Error Resume Next
     CurrentDb.QueryDefs.Delete "temp2"
 On Error GoTo 0

db.CreateQueryDef "temp2", mySql


DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12Xml, "temp2", CurrentProject.path & "\" & " IDS Generated" & Format(Now(), " mm dd yyyy hh mm"), True


CurrentDb.QueryDefs.Delete "temp2"
Set db = Nothing


DoCmd.SetWarnings True


MsgBox "List of IDS processed successfully"



Exit Sub

HandleError:
    MsgBox Err.Description

End Sub
```

Im trying to copy a List of IDs from a table on access into an specific Excel file on the first sheet call "Data" from cell A2 up to A101 if I have 100 ids, if i have 50 ids it would be from a2 to a51. I have no clue how to accomplish this. If anyone can point me in the right direction I would appreciate it

Comment: i think the answer will be found if you were to debug.print; CurrentProject.pat

Comment: Thank Doug Let me try that